# SuiteScript 2.0: Error thrown when applying partial customer payment against an invoice

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

I am using a map/reduce script to create a new customer payment record (from an invoice record) which is a partial payment of the invoice. This action needs to occur in the MAP stage.

Example: Amount due on the invoice is (say) £26.66, and I want to apply a £2.00 payment against this.

The following snippet appears to work when applying the FULL payment of the invoice:

```
        var customerpayment = record.transform({
            fromType : rectype, 
            fromId: recid, 
            toType: 'customerpayment',
            isDynamic: true
        })

            if (amount > 0){

            var linecount = customerpayment.getLineCount({ sublistId: 'apply' }); 

            for (var i = 1; i < linecount; i++) {
                
            var refnum = customerpayment.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'refnum', line: i });
                
                if (refnum == tranid) { 
                    log.audit ('refnum == tranid. Line no: ' + i, refnum + ' | ' + tranid); 
                    
                    //isDynamic = TRUE
                    customerpayment.selectLine({sublistId: 'apply', line: i });

                    //Mark "apply' FALSE to clear the apply box (this would clear the "payment" header field as well)
                    customerpayment.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'apply', value: false });

                    //Now set the payment header field with the amount you want to apply
                    customerpayment.setValue({fieldId: 'payment', value: amount});      
                   
                    //Now select TRUE on apply. This (should) copy/paste the payment amount automatically as it does via the UI.
                    customerpayment.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'apply', value: true });
                     
                    //For sanity sake, just populate the apply 'total' line with the same amount as payment field. In case it did not do it automatically.
                    customerpayment.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'total', value: amount });

                    var getTotal = customerpayment.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'total', line: i }); 
                    var getAllTotal = customerpayment.getValue({fieldId: 'payment'});                       

                    //Quick check that 'payment' header field and apply total field are the same
                    log.audit ('payment | payment line', getAllTotal + ' | ' + getTotal);   

                    break;
                }
            }
            
            //Now save record
            var payment_id = customerpayment.save({
                enableSourcing : true,
                ignoreMandatoryFields: true
            })
```

The same code above sadly fires the following error when adjusting amount that is SMALLER than the amount due on the invoice.

[image]

I have reached a holt at this point so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Interestingly, I have managed to create a user event script which successfully does just this.
Not sure if its down to the script type that could be preventing this action?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the same record gets mapped multiple times you will run out of funds to apply.  Do not do actions like that in the MAP phase.

Comment: Sure. But over two iterations in a loop, the first action of the function is to apply a partial payment, but this sadly fires the error. When that fails, the next iteration applies whatever is left to apply funds to. In this case, its the full amount of the invoice which successfully works with the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you create the payment record you have to set the payment amount at the body level. And since you are in dynamic mode you have to set it before you start applying.

```
customerpayment.setValue({fieldId:'payment', value:amount});
customerpayment.setValue({fieldId:'autoapply', value:false}); //so only the invoice of interest will receive the payment
```

then apply to your lines.

```
if(refNum == tranid){
   customerpayment.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'apply', value: true }); // IIRC this is all you need to do. I think in dynamic mode NS fills in the amount or the amount owing whichever is less. But if not proceed:

   var canApply = Math.min(amount, customerpayment.getCurrentSublistValue({sublistid:'apply', fieldId:'amount'}));

   customerpayment.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'amount', value: canApply});
   break;
}
```

Comment: This line:    customerpayment.setCurrentSublistValue({sublistId: 'apply', fieldId: 'amount', value: canApply}); - Should this not be "fieldId: 'total'?

Comment: No. The total is the sum of the amounts on the 'apply' and 'credit' sublists that apply to the line's transaction. e.g. in the UI you enter an 'amount' (in the column labeled 'Payment')  and it shows up on the 'total' (under Orig. Amt.).

Comment: Thank you for assistance. Is there a way to programmatically 'Clear' all flags which are marked TRUE on 'Apply', without needing to run a loop on every line entry (which could have up to 10000)? Something similar to the existing 'Clear' button on the payment record would be helpful. Reason I ask is because, for some reason or another, the script (appears to) randomly apply payment to a completely different invoice (from what was originally transformed)

Comment: Your script will run faster if you don’t use dynamic mode. You can also play with the initialization parameters to see if you can open it with auto-apply false

Comment: I found that I needed to also loop through all rows and set the apply field to false. NetSuite was setting apply=true on a one single row.